# How to Force browser to load javascript response even it is a 401 unauthorized response

Tags: javascript, firefox

My situation here is when I embed this snippet in my html page

`<script src=https://foo.com/yyy.js> /*yyy.js returns 200*/ </script>`
it (Chrome, FireFox, IE) works fine reading the content of yyy.js, when the response is 200.

However when I embed this snippet instead
`<script src=https://foo.com/xxx.js> /*xxx.js returns 401*/ </script>`
it doesn't load the content of 401 unauthorized script.

My question is how could I force browser (Safari, FireFox, Chrome or IE) to read the content of the script even the response is 401.

Comment: If the specified URL is unauthorised then the server won't send the script to the browser in the first place, so the browser has nothing to read.

Comment: If there was a (legitimate) way, that would make security pointless.

Comment: The server is actually sending the script to browser even its 401 unauthorized, thats why I want to force browser to read it anyway.